# Ajax only deletes upon refresh in Ruby app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to create a to-do list app in Rails which consists of many to-do lists and each list has as many to-do items. When I try to destroy a completed to-do item with Ajax, I have to refresh the page before it disappears.  I'm new to Rails and Javascript, so any thoughts would be appreciated.

Here's my Items destroy Javascript file:

```
<% if @item.destroyed? %>
$('#item-' +<%= @item.id %>).hide();
<% else %>
$('#item-' +<%= @item.id %>).prepend("<div class='alert alert-danger'><%= flash[:error] %></div>");
<% end %>
```

The Lists#show view that calls the item partial:

```
%h1= @title
.row
  .col-md-6
    = render 'items/item', locals: {items: @items}
.row
  .col-md-6
    = render 'items/form', locals: {list: @list, item: @item}

= link_to "Edit", edit_list_path(@list), class: 'btn btn-success'

= link_to "Delete List", @list, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this to-do list?' }

- if @lists.nil?
  = link_to "New To-do List", new_list_path, class: 'btn btn-success'
```

The Item partial:

```
- @items.each do |item|
  = item.name
  = link_to "", [item.list, item], method: :delete, class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok', remote: true
  %br/
```

Items Controller:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js

  def create
    @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
    @item = @list.items.new(item_params)
    @item.user_id = current_user.id
    if @item.save
      redirect_to @list, notice: 'Your new To-Do Item was saved!'
    else
      redirect_to @list, notice: 'You forgot to enter a To-Do item. Please try again.'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @list = current_user.lists.find(params[:list_id])
    @item = @list.items.find(params[:id])
    @title = @list.title

    if @item.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "\"#{@item.name}\" was deleted successfully."
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error deleting the list."
    end

    respond_with(@item) do |format|
      format.html {render [@list]}
    end
  end

  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app sends a delete request when the link created by `= link_to "", [item.list, item], method: :delete, class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok', remote: true` is clicked, but does not change the view. You need to add an event listener that catches that ajax delete request is succeeded and hides the item element in the view.

Here's a rough code to achieve that. I didn't test the code but I think you can get the idea.

item partial:

```
.item-container
  - @items.each do |item|
    .item
      = item.name
      = link_to "", [item.list, item], method: :delete, class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok', remote: true
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.item-container').on('ajax:success', function() {
    $(this).closest('.item').hide();
  });
};
```

References:

- http://api.jquery.com/on/
- http://tech.thereq.com/post/17243732577/rails-3-using-link-to-remote-true-with-jquery
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to-label-Options

By the way, where do you place the piece of JavaScript code you posted? I doubt it is ever executed.

Comment: I used the code you suggested, but I'm still having the same issue.  I have to reload the page to delete the item.  I'm thinking maybe, as you suggested, the JS isn't being called.

Comment: The JS code is in app/views/items/destroy.js.erb . According to the checkpoint I'm following on the lesson to create the app, it says " The Rails convention is to name the .js.erb view corresponding to the controller action, so in this case app/views/comments/destroy.js.erb. This file will have access to the instance variables a regular view would have."  So, according to this, I thought I placed the only code I needed.  Do I need to place a call somewhere for the JS to be executed?

Answer (score 0):

Not terribly familiar with HAML, but it looks like you are not adding an `ID` in your view. Your `destroy.js.erb` is looking for a selector like `id=item-1` in order to hide it. Therefore, your item partial needs to be populated with an id in order to find it later. In ERB, I'd do:

```
<ul>
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  <li id="item-" + item.id><%= item.name %> </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Something like that :)